# Why does base class pointer to a derived class object with overridden method call a base class method?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    void show() { cout<<" In Base \n"; }
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    void show() { cout<<"In Derived \n"; }
};

int main(void)
{
    Base *bp = new Derived;
    bp->show(); // RUN-TIME POLYMORPHISM
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, `show()` is  declared in the base class and is overriden in the derived class. The base class pointer `bp` points to a derived class object. Now, when `bp` to call the non virtual `show()` function.

**Output:**

```
In Base
```

But, `bp` points to derived class, so why the base's function is called rather than the derived class function?

Comment: Recommended reading: [When to use virtual destructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)

Answer (score 4):

> `// RUN-TIME POLYMORPHISM`

In C++ it's opt-in. For a function call to be resolved polymorphically at run-time, the programmer must explicitly say that's desired by marking it `virtual`.

The reason is that dynamic dispatch is never without a cost, and a staple of C++'s design is that "you don't pay for what you don't need". You must say you really need it for it to be enabled.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `show()` virtual to allow kicking in of runtime polymorphism.

```
virtual void show() { cout<<" In Base \n"; }
```

Comment: I know, but base pointer point to derived then why call base function?

Comment: @Jayesh Because if the function is not `virtual`, C++ does not generate the code for a `Base` to invoke `Derived`'s override. There is a small performance hit using runtime polymorphism, and C++ has a policy of not making a program pay more than the programmer asked for.

Comment: @Jayesh Without `virtual` the binding of `show()` and its body is not delayed, hence no polymorphism.

Comment: Additional fun fact: When you declare a function to be `virtual`, all overrides of that function in derived classes are `virtual` unless `final` is invoked. Also look into and get used to using the `override` keyword. It's very handy in catching mistakes like this.

Comment: @Jayesh ,without the keyword "Virtual " Vptr and Vtable never got created ,the binding to the constructor of child class never happened ,hence it remains with the base class.

Answer (score 2):

The core issue here is that `show` method is *not* overridden in the derived class. Starting with C++11 you can use `override` specifier to ensure that method really does override something so compiler will detect this problem for your:

```
class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    void show() override { cout<<"In Derived \n"; }
};
```

> prog.cc:13:10: error: 'void Derived::show()' marked 'override', but does not override

In order to override a method it should be declared as `virtual` in base class:

```
class Base
{
    public: virtual
    void show() { cout<<" In Base \n"; }
};
```

Comment: Upvoted for mentioning `override`, which was invented for this exact bug.

Answer (score 1):

To complement the other answers posted here, with reference to this comment:

> I know, but base pointer point to derived then why call base function?

Please see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50830338/5743288

It follows, therefore, that if you were to do this:

```
Derived *dp = new Derived;
dp->show();
```

You would get the following output:

```
In Derived
```

even without declaring `show()` as `virtual` (because the compiler would then know which method *you have said* that you want to call).

So, as others point out, if you want the service you have to pay the price (although, even with your original code, the compiler would probably be smart enough to optimise out the virtual function call anyway, see [here](https://godbolt.org/g/AzggLd)).

Answer (score 1):

Most folks have already answered that you need to declare a function to be `virtual` for it to bind at runtime when your code executes. 
I want to add that without virtual, the method to be called is decided at compile time and it will pick the method of the class whose variable/pointer type you declared. In your case, `Base` class type.

Additionally, would like to provide a good to read link which can help clear your concept of runtime polymorphism in C++ : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/virtual-function-cpp/

Answer (score 0):

This is actually what is call RUN TIME POLYMORPHISM. And in C++ its programmers discretion to call desired function of base or derived class, based on the object given to base class pointer.

Irrespective of the base class pointer pointing to any derived class object. If the function being called is non-virtual then always base class function will be called to a base class pointer.

To call derived class function from a base class pointer the function must be marked as `virtual`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(void)
{
    Base *bp = new Derived;
    bp->show(); // RUN-TIME POLYMORPHISM
    return 0;
}
```

compiler bind it with base class object while compiling 
    "new Derived" passing object to base but it been binded with base object it refer to same class
    once if you add virtual binding will happen run time and once object passed by derived it bind with drived class

Answer (score 0):

In c++,even-though you make the base class pointer point to derived class object, it still calls the function from the base class, this is because of Early binding, so in order to achieve Late binding make the function inside the base class as **virtual**.
i.e., virtual void show()
{
.......
}
Now, the o/p will be "In Derived".